# What does Low/High mean on the connections of a chip?

Tags: integrated-circuit

This is similar to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7888/meaning-of-set-low-set-high), but that seems to apply more towards programming microcontrollers rather than directly setting hardware-controlled chips. I have a PCM5102A, and [the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm5102a.pdf) tells me to make selections by setting the pin to "low" or "high".

Here's a sample:

[image]

The datasheet doesn't say anything about how to implement this. What should I do if I want to set it to LOW, and what should I do for HIGH? Should I add voltage, connect the pin to ground, leave it...

Answer (score 3):

A "low" is a voltage lower than or equal to the maximum low input voltage (V<sub>IL</sub>) given in the datasheet. A "high" is a voltage higher than or equal to the minimum high input voltage (V<sub>IH</sub>) given in the datasheet.

Comment: If I want a "low", can I just leave the pin blank and not connect it to anything?

Comment: Absolutely not. Unconnected pins should be considered "floating", which means they will act as an antenna and can have any arbitrary voltage on them.

Comment: So I should apply voltage, but use a resistor to keep the value at either "high" or "low"? Sorry, but I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: You don't need a resistor. Tie the inputs either high or low, or connect them to a logic output.

Comment: If you want an input to be Low, you just connect it to circuit ground.  If you want it High, you connect it to the chip's positive supply, usually +3.3 or +5 volts - if there's a higher voltage on the chip, you should study the datasheet to determine the voltage that that pin will consider as High.