# LOW and HIGH definition for Enable pin of 4051?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, analog, mixed-signal

Suppose we have connected an X volt (X=10) as the supply of a 4051 MUX (which is active LOW), can we disable the device by applying a B volte (assume B is 5 volt). In other words, how high is HIGH relative to the supply voltage?

Comment: Read the data sheet - it will tell you the digital logic levels for 1 and 0.

Comment: thanks Andy, I've did already, but I couldn't find anything on that. I'll take a look again now.

Comment: Just look at the datasheet. Any good one will have logic levels on it.

Comment: At the very least, if you want us to show you where to look in the datasheet, you need to give us the exact part number. There are several different families that contain '4051 parts and each one has different logic level definitions. Even better would be a link to the datasheet for the exact part number you're interested in.

Comment: OK, it seems I've find something relevant, so I'm going to edit the post accordingly.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111179/what-does-low-high-mean-on-the-connections-of-a-chip?rq=1

Comment: For 4000-series CMOS logic, the standard is: logic low is 0..30% Vdd; logic high is 70..100% Vdd. Stay out of 30..70% Vdd, the chip's entitled to logically misbehave. (There are applications that do things in this range to get 'linear mode' from the IC but put that aside for pure logic circuits.) Take nothing for granted, always check the data sheet.

Comment: Thanks tony, I think your comments worth it to a an answer.

Comment: The 4051 has internal level shifting- the guaranteed logic level 1 is 0.7*(Vdd - Vss) **relative to Vss**, and Vee does not affect it, at least for Vee <= Vss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here it is (at least for the CD4051/52): -

[image]

This is from the first 4051 data sheet found. On a 10 volt supply the high level must be at least 7 volts. It's a 70%:30% thing.

Comment: exactly, you got it!